# javascript: break a recursive call after a time duration

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, recursion

I am trying to execute a recursive AJAX call to handle one of the functionality in my application. The scenario is as below:

1. Execute an AJAX function
2. The server can return two different values, example: String A or String B
3. If response is String B, the same AJAX  function is called again.

I want to make sure that if the server returns String B as the response for more than two minutes, the recursive execution should stop and an error message should be displayed to the user.

Can someone suggest an appropriate way for doing this?

Here is the sample JS code. We are using ExtJS:

```
function process()
{

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : "ABC.action",
        form: 'formname',
        params:{
            method : "Serversidehandler",

        },
        success : processSuccess,
        failure : processFail

    }); 

}

function processSuccess(request) 
{
    if(request.responseText != null)
    {
        var responseJSON = Ext.decode(request.responseText);
        var response = responseJSON.response;
        if(response != null) 
        {

            if(response == "A")
            {
                // do something
            }
            else if(response == "B")
            {
                process() // main method called again
            }

        } 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try the below given code, setTimeout works fine with the delays.**

Kindly specify the requirement more clearly.

```
 function process()
    {
    
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url : "ABC.action",
            form: 'formname',
            params:{
                method : "Serversidehandler",
    
            },
            success : processSuccess,
            failure : processFail
    
        }); 
    
    }
    
    function processSuccess(request) 
    {
        if(request.responseText != null)
        {
            var responseJSON = Ext.decode(request.responseText);
            var response = responseJSON.response;
            if(response != null) 
            {
    
                if(response == "A")
                {
                    // do something
                }
                else if(response == "B")
                {
                    window.setTimeout(process(), 2000); // main method called again
                }
    
            } 
        } 
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var startTime = (new Date).getTime();

function process() {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: "ABC.action",
        form: 'formname',
        params: {
            method: "Serversidehandler",
        },
        success: processSuccess,
        failure: processFail
    });
}

function processSuccess(request) {
    var elapsedTime = 0;
    if (request.responseText != null) {
        var responseJSON = Ext.decode(request.responseText);
        var response = responseJSON.response;
        if (response != null) {
            if (response == "A") {
                // do something
            }
            else if (response == "B") {
                elapsedTime = (new Date().getTime()) - startTime;
                if (elapsedTime <= 2000) {
                    process() // main method called again
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```